# Replacing strings in TXT file

Tags: batch-file, replace, cmd

I want to replace a line in a text file. The script below works to remove the line, but it replaces the line with true==true. I know it's due to how I have `>>"%textFile%" echo(!line:%search%=%!)` set up. I would like it to just delete the line, then I can echo out the replace variable, but I am having issues figuring out how to do that.

```
@echo off &setlocal
set "search=xxxxx"
set "replace=yyyyy"
set "search_1=zzzzz"
set "replace_1=aaaaa"
set "textfile=%userprofile%\AppData\....."
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('type "%textFile%" ^& break ^> "%textFile%" ') do (
    set "line=%%i"
    >>"%textFile%" echo(!line:%search%=%!)
>>"%textFile%" echo(%replace%
endlocal
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('type "%textFile%" ^& break ^> "%textFile%" ') do (
    set "line=%%i"
    >>"%textFile%" echo(!line:%search_1%=%!)
>>"%textFile%" echo(%replace_1%
endlocal
)
```

Comment: I have formatted your code to show its indentation which highlights that you have an unpaired closing parenthesis on the last line. You also need to find out what `endlocal` does because in your second for loop all of `%textFile%`, `%search_1%` and `%replace_1%` have become undefined, i.e. have no value. You also appear to be using delayed expansion, but your code does not enable it!

Comment: `!line:%search%=!` *removes* the search string. To *replace* it, `!line:%search%=%replace%!`